# how do I use or reuse the same map signature/arguments/variables across different server configurations in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

I am trying to get some redirection done via nginx maps. I have separate server blocks for individual domains,[and their aliases], say:

- www.example.fr
- www.example.uk
- www.example.nl

Each within its conf file, say: www.example.fr.conf for example.

In each server configuration file, I am setting up the redirection using maps, so there is a [redirection] map for each domain like so:

```
include france-redirects.conf;
server {
   server_name  www.example.fr example.fr;
   ...
   if ($redirect_uri) {
        return 301 $redirect_uri;
    } 
}
```

the file: france-redirects.conf looks like this:

```
map $request_uri $redirect_uri {        
    ~/news https://www.example.com/france/latest-news;
    ~/about http://www.example.com/france/about;
}
```

And this works as expected: so that traffic to http://www.example.fr/news gets redirected to https://www.example.com/france/latest-news

However, when I create similar configurations for other domains. The problem starts and seems to be that I am not able to use the same map signature/arguments/variables:

```
map $request_uri $redirect_uri {}
```

repeated in other server configuration files. Nginx seems to select the first map block [not sure what the order is] and 'obeys' that only. So when I have:

```
include netherlands-redirects.conf;
server {
   server_name  www.example.nl example.nl;

   if ($redirect_uri) {
        return 301 $redirect_uri;
    } 
}
```

with the map file [netherlands-redirects.conf] like so:

```
map $request_uri $redirect_uri {        
    ~/news https://www.example.com/netherlands/latest-news;
    ~/about http://www.example.com/netherlands/about;
}
```

and I try curling to see the final redirect:

```
curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} http://www.example.nl/news
```

it would return something like:

```
http://www.example.com/france/latest-news
```

I am trying to avoid lumping all redirects into one long file but rather split them based on domains. Is this not possible or am I going about it the wrong way? Hope my explanation makes sense. Please help. Thanks

Comment: All of your `map` statements are in the same `http` block. You will need to give them unique variable names.

Comment: Does you redirects differ only in first part (france, netherland, etc...)?

Comment: @RichardSmith: Thanks. could you give me an idea how to go about this? How and where do I set the individual variables?

Comment: @AlexeyTen: Thanks Alexey, the redirects would have both. i.e. identical [/news /latest-new] as well as those which would be unique to the domain.

Comment: The variable `$redirect_uri` is global, so you define it three times. You need to use a unique target name in all of your `map` blocks.

Comment: @RichardSmith: Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` directive is global for all `server` blocks. So you have to use different variable names. E.g.

```
map $request_uri $redirect_uri_fr {        
    ~/news https://www.example.com/france/latest-news;
    ~/about http://www.example.com/france/about;
}

map $request_uri $redirect_uri_nl {        
    ~/news https://www.example.com/netherlands/latest-news;
    ~/about http://www.example.com/netherlands/about;
}
```

and use them corresponding `server` blocks:

```
include france-redirects.conf;
server {
   server_name  www.example.fr example.fr;
   ...
   if ($redirect_uri) {
        return 301 $redirect_uri_fr;
    } 
} 

include netherlands-redirects.conf;
server {
   server_name  www.example.nl example.nl;

   if ($redirect_uri) {
        return 301 $redirect_uri_nl;
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is precisely what I have done and confirmed to be the solution, based on what @Richard mentioned earlier. This works. Thanks